# 'this' scope in regular function vs arrow function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

`myRegFunc` refers to `this` with local scope limited to `users` object. However, `myArrowFunc` instead refers to `this` with global scope. Is there a way to reference the same `this` information in the arrow function as is available from the regular function?

So the arrow func cannot bind to the local this? However, is it possible to still get the local this information through the global this? For example: global this.something.something ... = the local this.

```
const users = {
  name: 'John',
  myRegFunc: function() {
    console.log('myRegFunc : ', this);
  },
  myArrowFunc: () => console.log('myArrowFunc this: ', this),
};
users.myRegFunc();
users.myArrowFunc();
```

Output:

```
myRegFunc :  {name: 'John', myRegFunc: ƒ, myArrowFunc: ƒ}
arrowFunc.js:34 myArrowFunc this:  Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
```

Comment: No, that's one of the _points_ of arrow functions. If you want a regular function's behaviour, use a regular function.

Comment: OK, I can't bind to 'this' from the arrow func. However, is it possible to reference the local this from the global 'this' by drilling down a path? For example 'this.something.something.something ...'?

Comment: You have the reference. It is `users`. As for arrow functions, there is no such `this` reference *created*, so there is no generic way to reference it -- it just isn't there at all. Within arrow functions `this` has the same value as immediately around that arrow function.

Comment: Can you show an example that works?

Comment: It already "works" as intended. Just read the comment above and the linked duplicate reference that was put as the question was closed.

Comment: Er, you have an example that works in your question:, using a non-arrow function function.

Comment: Fair enough. A non-arrow is my only option. Thanks for the feedback.